# Query wait conditions with API?

Tags: control-m

Can the Control-M API be used to find out what conditions a job in the current NEWDAY is waiting on?

I realize this is a simple question, but I do not yet have access to use the Control-M API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like that functionality has made it to the API as yet (not that I could see, anyway).

However, there is the **ctmcontb** utility (available on Server and Agent) that can be added to scripts.